# TypeScript array to hold generic types with different type parameters

Tags: typescript, generics, variance

In TypeScript, how can I get the `holders` constant below to hold `Holder` instances with unspecified generic type parameters? This would be useful, for example, if the type parameter is not relevant for the operations that examine the objects in the array.

```
interface Data {
    [field: string]: any;
}

class Holder<T extends Data> {
    constructor(readonly item: T) {
    }
}

const holders: Array<Holder<unknown>> = [];
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGSOQG0ZgIAbAEwC5kBnMKUAcwF164QBPAbgIBfAgQSU4DBsgASAexrQAPABVkEAB6QQ1KekwA+HAWLIEskEygBXBGFlQAFFAhxq5yj2TBIAW3rKASiNCYmF8MNFzJmQAC3lqaAZ6AEEoKDgeRTkFKEUrEABrEFkAdxB9QwBeUnY+IA

This sample fails to compile with this error:

```
Type 'unknown' does not satisfy the constraint 'Data'. (2344)
```

*Is there a syntax like `unknown extends Data` that I could use, or something like that?*

If I change

```
class Holder<T extends Data> {
```

to just

```
class Holder<T> {
```

then it compiles successfully.

Also, using `any` instead of `unknown` compiles successfully; however, I want to be "safer" and use `unknown` instead of `any`.

Comment: Given that `Holder<T>` seems to be covariant in `T`, can you just write `Array<Holder<Data>>`?  If not, could you [edit] the question with code that demonstrates why that doesn't work?

Comment: Okay that may solve my problem. Let me see if I run into any other type issues. Thank you.